# A little confused about subnet masks

Tags: networking, ip, routing

I still don't have a really clear understanding of subnet masks, and I want to understand it better, but right now I urgently need an answer to just one question:

If my computer's subnet mask is 255.255.0.0, can I connect directly to a device with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0?

For instance, if I had my PC set up with an IP address of 192.168.1.100, with a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0, and a gateway of 192.168.1.1, would I be able to directly connect to a device (e.g. Raspberry Pi) with an IP address of 192.168.1.150, with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0, and a gateway of 192.168.1.1?

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Both devices are in the same network (same gateway) and the PC could have a subnet mask of `255.255.255.0`

Answer (score 1):

This setup is incorrect, but it will work in the case where both IPs are
legal in both networks.

The reason is that nodes find one another through 
[ARP requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol)
where a request is broadcast, for example, asking
"Who has `192.168.1.150`, tell `192.168.1.100`".

The request will pass through all connected routers/switches, since the
ARP request does not include any data about subnet masks,
only about IP and MAC address.

Once `192.168.1.150` (or its router) received the request, it will answer
with the MAC address of `192.168.1.150`.
From now on communication will pass to Layer 2, also known as the
[Data link layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer).

The Layer 2 frames will use MAC address as source and destination,
which the router/switch will happily pass along.

Comment: It won't pass through any switch as both devices have the same gateway and are on the same network.