# Networking - Can computers with different subnets talk to each other if one has the wrong subnet?

Tags: networking

I have two computers on two different subnets:

```
10.0.3.1/24
```

and

```
10.0.4.1/16
```

Neither computers have gateways.

So, `10.0.3.1` can reach from `10.0.3.0-10.0.3.255` and `10.0.4.1` can reach from `10.0.0.0` to `10.0.255.255`. This means `10.0.3.1` cannot reach `10.0.4.1`, but `10.0.4.1` possibly could.
I am unable to test this, and would like to know:
Can 10.0.4.1 and 10.0.3.1 communicate at all? Can 10.0.4.1 send packets to 10.0.3.1, even if it gets no reply?

Both computers are connected directly via ethernet.

Comment: Try this article here to connect subnets:  https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-connect-computers-that-are-on-2-different-subnets  . I find it vastly simpler in a small environment to have one subnet only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A little confused about subnet masks](https://superuser.com/questions/1458382/a-little-confused-about-subnet-masks)

Comment: In this question, are both computers connected directly to the same ethernet (e.g. using a direct cable or through a switch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer concern only case where IP protocol is used.

When a computer has to send packet to another, it check if the other is on the same subnet by using IP address and subnet mask.

- If the other is on the same subnet, it send the packet directly to him.
- If the other is not on the same subnet, it send the packet to the appropriate router according its routing table, this router is generally the gateway. So if there isn't gateway, the packet cannot be sent.

In your example, 10.0.4.1 can send packet to the other host even if it has no gateway since the other host is on its subnet. The other host will get it (you can check it by running network sniffer like Wireshark on 10.0.3.1).
But no response will be send back to 10.0.4.1 because 10.0.3.1 need a gateway to reach this host being on another subnet from its point of view.